# Is O(n Log n) in polynomial time?

Tags: big-o

Is O(n Log n) in polynomial time?  If so, could you explain why?

I am interested in a mathematical proof, but I would be grateful for any strong intuition as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Yes, O(nlogn) is polynomial time.

From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialTime.html,

> An algorithm is said to be solvable in polynomial time if the number
> of steps required to complete the algorithm for a given input is
> O(n^m) for some nonnegative integer m, where n is the complexity of
> the input.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation,

> f is O(g) iff
>
> [image: $ \hspace{1px} \exists k > 0 \hspace{3px} \exists n_0 \hspace{3px} \forall n > n_0: \hspace{3px} | f(n) | \leq | g(n) \cdot k | \hspace{1px}$]

I will now prove that n log n is O(n^m) for some m which means that n log n is polynomial time.

Indeed, take m=2.  (this means I will prove that n log n is O(n^2))

For the proof, take k=2. (This could be smaller, but it doesn't have to.)
There exists an n_0 such that for all larger n the following holds.

n_0 * f(n) <= g(n) * k

Take n_0 = 1 (this is sufficient)
It is now easy to see that

n log n <= 2n*n

log n <= 2n

n > 0 (assumption)

Click [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%20n%20%3C=%202*n) if you're not sure about this.

This proof could be a lot nicer in latex math mode, but I don't think stackoverflow supports that.

Comment: How about proving that `log n <= 2n`? :)

Comment: 1. That `n_0` shouldn't be there. 2. To prove that `logn < 2n`, I'll just prove that `logn < n < 2n`. This becomes `h(n) = log(n)/n < 1`. This is true for `n = n0 = 1` (`0<1`) and you can focus on showing that `h(n)` is a **monotonically decreasing function**.

Answer (score 5):

It is, because it is upper-bounded by a polynomial (n).
You could take a look at the graphs and go from there, but I can't formulate a mathematical proof other than that :P

EDIT: From the wikipedia page, "An algorithm is said to be of polynomial time if its running time is upper bounded by a polynomial expression in the size of the input for the algorithm".

Answer (score 4):

It is at least not worse than polynomial time. And still not better: n < n log n < n*n.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong!
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation , 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity and
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialTime.html

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly is wrong here? (Also note that in computer science Big-O is often used in a sense of Big-Theta.)

Comment: O(n^2) is still polynomial time.
The fact that n < n log n < n*n holds for large n is indeed true. n log n is not linear time, but dat does not mean that n lon n is not polynomial time. I will consider adding a mathematical proof to my answer.

Comment: I have now added a mathematical proof :D

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I am always eager to improve my understanding and my answers. However, I believe I have never said that O(n^2) is not polynomial, or that O(n log n) is not.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I think I misread your answer. The equation at the end confused me. It seemed to suggest that O(n^2) is not polynomial time.

Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. What's the limit of nlogn as n goes to infinity? Intuitively, for large n, n >> logn and you can consider the product dominated by n and so nlogn ~ n, which is clearly polynomial time. A more rigorous proof is by using the the Sandwich theorem which Inspired did:

n^1 < nlogn < n^2.

Hence nlogn is bounded above (and below) by a sequence which is polynomial time.

Comment: I didn't say it was 1, if we're being pedantic we could say that n dominates the limit of nlogn as n goes to infinity. Strictly speaking, a sequence which tends to infinity diverges.

And if you have two functions f(n)*g(n) then the limit if the product is lim f(n) * lim g(n), which in this case is infinity*infinity, which is undefined.

Comment: "the limit of nlogn as n goes to infinity" is "n which is n^1".  Could you explain that statement a little further then?

Comment: I did already. To repeat: as n goes to infinity, n >> logn. Hence, you can basically ignore the contribution of logn to nlogn as n goes to infinity, leaving you with just n. This is not "rigorous", but the guy asked for intuition...

Comment: But you're essentially saying that "`log(n)=o(n)`, so `log(n)=O(1)`".  I agree that ignoring the logarithm is a good way to intuitively start seeing how `nlog(n)` grows, but we can't ignore it completely.  To make my point a different way: if we change `log` to `sqrt`, you still have `n>>sqrt(n)`, but `n^1.5` does not grow like `n`.